# Where do you begin when you enter in the OASIS?

Tags: plot-explanation, ready-player-one

In the movie [*Ready Player One*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready_Player_One_(film)), we can see that a user can logout of the OASIS by removing the goggles (if they are not engaged in a fight). What happens if they login back next time? Will they start from where they left or do they have a choice where to go?

Did I miss something? I haven't read the novel yet.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't explicitly stated anywhere in the book (that I recall).

However, in the book, Parzival has to do a lot of traveling around within the OASIS to get from place to place.  The implication is that players go back to where they left the last session.  At the start of the book, Parzival appears in school on Ludus, where he's stuck because he can't afford a ship or the teleportation fees to go anyplace else.

Note that in the book, there are chatrooms (Aech's one in particular) where they can jump to, but they still continue their OASIS session when they exit the chatroom.

I'd really recommend that you read the novel.

Answer (score 1):

The book suggests you return to the same spot you logged off:

> **0002:**
>
> My avatar materialized in front of my locker on the second floor of my
>   high school - the exact spot where I'd been standing when I'd logged
>   out the night before.